# "File f = new File("//Dev/Test")" in beanshellsampler JMeter

Tags: file, jmeter, beanshell

Trying to get the files from filepath using java.io.File "File f = new File("//DEV/Test")" in beanshellsampler JMeter configured in Jenkins, when try to get the absolute path, getting only  "/Dev/Test". one '/' is missing.

```
String folderPath = "//Dev/Test";

#oneway
File folder = new File(folderPath);
folder.toAbsolutePath(); //output :: /Dev/Test

#Secondway
Path p1 = Paths.get(foldertoString, new String[0]);
File pathtoFile = p1.toFile(); 
String[] fn = pathtoFile.list();
// output : path is not correct
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not missing, [`/` is the root of the Linux file system](https://opensource.com/life/16/10/introduction-linux-filesystems), there is no need to have an extra slash there.

Also be informed that [starting from JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so consider migrating on next available opportunity.

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)